# Every truth function of the inderterminates X and Y is an iterated composition of negations and disjunctions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm reading K.T.Leung and Doris L.C.Chen's Elementary set theory.I can't solve [exercise 10](http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=dmo1Dntlzq4C&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=every%20truth%20function%20of%20the%20indeterminates%20X%20and%20Y%20is%20an%20iterated%20composition%20of%20negations%20and%20disjunctions&source=bl&ots=AsGj7oR6ZD&sig=i7jx6NiQvFIx1IMn4ESZKe-Rrm4&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=Stf-UsjIAej_iAeExYFQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=every%20truth%20function%20of%20the%20indeterminates%20X%20and%20Y%20is%20an%20iterated%20composition%20of%20negations%20and%20disjunctions&f=false): 
Prove that every truth function of the inderterminates X and Y is an iterated composition of negations and disjunctions.
Can you help me?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the idea is just to show that you can get $\wedge$, $\to$, $\leftrightarrow$ out of just $\neg$ and $\vee$.

To give you a hint to get started, we'll translate $X\wedge Y$. This sentence is clearly true exactly when both $X,Y$ are true; that is, we know it is false exactly when $\neg X\vee\neg Y$, and therefore true when $\neg(\neg X\vee\neg Y)$. It's easy to check a truth table to see that they come out the same.

In general, look at the truth table for a given connective and form the alternation of all the expressions involving $X,Y$ that must be *true* for the total expression to come out *false*; then negate that alternation. (In the example of conjunction abover, the truth table for $X\wedge Y$ comes out F when $\neg X$ is true or when $\neg Y$ is true, so I form their alternation and negate it.)

Hopefully that was clear.

Comment: I think the "every truth function" bit means all 16 functions that take two truth values and return one. It would have been more fun if user123943 were asked to prove that ["NOR" suffices all on its own](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR#Properties).

Comment: Either way, the same approach works. And yes, NAND and NOR are lots more fun; in my heart, $\downarrow$ is the only truth functional connective.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thanks for your answer.Since I'm a beginner,I'm actually confused that what  the sixteen distinct truth functions refer to in the hint.

Comment: Well, they're not part of my hint and aren't necessary to solve the problem, but the idea is: say we have a mystery truth function on two indeterminates, which we can write $X*Y$. Now fill out a truth table so the first two columns cover all the possible assignments of true or false to $X,Y$ (there are only four). Then there are 16 possible ways we can fill out the last column for the total expression $X*Y$, and each way we fill it out gives us a different truth function. In practice, we don't need symbols for all sixteen since we can define the rest from a small number of others.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thanks very much.The sixteen distinct truth functions really scared me.

Comment: See [Adequate set of connectives](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~lila/logic/adequate.pdf)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you.That pdf file helps me a lot!